# How to change the value of a readonly textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I change the value of a HTML textbox which has readonly property using jQuery?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems a reasonable, if terse, question.

Comment: Been asked many times before (meaning he didn't search before posting) and I could have figure out the answer in 10 seconds by googling it.

Comment: @Phil That's funny because when I googled for it, I got this page.

Answer (score 20):

Wait, did you want to remove the read only? If so:

```
$('textbox').removeAttr('readonly').val('Changed Value');
```

if not:

```
$('textbox').val('Changed Value');
```

Comment: In current versions of jQuery, it might be better to use `.prop('readonly',false)` instead of `.removeAttr('readonly')`

Answer (score 16):

```
$('my-textbox').val('new value')
```

The read only property only applies to the user viewing the page, not the JavaScript that accesses. it

Answer (score 16):

older post but here´s some info.

if u have a readonly input (with id test), you just set the val with jquery

```
$('#test').val(100);
```

but if you look into html source code in your browser and search in your recently update input value, u will see value empty.

```
<input type="text" id="test" value />
```

so, to prevent this, you have to remove readonly atribute before set the value to the input and then set readonly to true again.

```
$('#test').prop('readonly',false);
$('#test').val(100);
$('#test').prop('readonly',true);
```

and the result in html

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="100" />
```

this prevent error when u need to send form values...

Comment: should be the top answer

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add a $('#test').trigger('change') after setting the value for it to clear my required field validation

Answer (score 6):

```
$('input[readonly]').val('my new val');
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to write the #
For example

```
$('#my-textbox').val('new value');
```

And maybe you can go through
Then after everything don't forget to try using "" instead of ''

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a case where it wasn't updating because I was using a datepicker on the textbox; so I had to use something like this to "trigger" the update:

```
$('#Date').val(date).datepicker('update', date)
```

I was also using the **readonly** attribute, but that had nothing to do with it.