# Place jquery result in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I am currently assigning the result of a calculation to a `<p>` element, and I would like the make the same assignment to an input field.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selector" onChange="Expedisi(this);">
            <option>Select product</option>
          <optgroup label="Sedan">
            <option value="Lancer EX">Lancer EX 1.6 / 2.0</option>
            <option value="Lancer EX GT">Lancer EX GT</option>
          <optgroup label="Sport">
            <option value="Lancer Evolution X">Lancer Evolution X</option>
          <optgroup label="SUV">
            <option value="Outlander">Outlander</option>
        </select>

<p id="thetotal"> </p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#selector').on('change', function() {
    total = data[$(this).val()].price;

    $('#thetotal').text("" + total);
})
```

The `change` handler will do the assignment, based on which option has been selected in the `#selector` element.  I know how to retrieve the selected option's value and how to calculate the `total`, as I'm already assigning this to a `<p>` element.

How do I assign the same value to an `input` element?  I just need to know which jQuery method is used to set the input element's value.

Comment: Do you want to [set the selector option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252664/how-can-i-programmatically-change-a-select-box-selection-from-within-the-control) or [set a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668364/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-readonly-textbox-using-jquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close in your jQuery code.  The way to set the contents of a text input field is with the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.  Using this, your code would look like this:

```
$('#selector').on('change', function() {
    var total = data[$(this).val()].price;

    $('#thetotal').val("" + total);
});
```

Two additional improvements have been made here, in case they existed in the actual code:

- Added `var` to the `total` variable assignment, so that the code doesn't accidentally create (or worse, overwrite) a global variable
- Added a `;` at the end of the code, after registering the event handler callback

The assignment of `total` assumes that there's a variable named `data` in scope, and that variable has members with values corresponding to the options in `#selector`.  This means that `data` would look something like this:

```
var data = {
    "Lancer EX": { price: 17995 },
    "Lancer EX GT": { price: 21873 },
    "Lancer Evolution X": { price: 26434 },
    "Outlander": { price: 21659 }
};
```

*This data is entirely made up, based on the data structure, so don't rely on it for anything other than understanding the code.  You've been warned.*

Comment: Yes now it works thank you for your information

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the total in an input field, just put this code in your `onchange` callback:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input'); // your input field
input.value = total;
```